# How to increase JSTree drop area

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using the jstree to build up tasks on a calender. I have set the div on which the tree is initialised to a min height of 50px, which means when I am dragging the first node onto an empty tree I can drop it anywhere within that 50px which is great.

However if I then want to drop another node (onto main tree branch) I now much drop it almost on top of the previous node, which means the user needs to be very exact about where they are dropping

Here is the div container

here is the code where the JSTree is attached:

```
    dayTree = moment.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    $('#' + dayTree).jstree({
        "core": {
            "id": moment.format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
            "animation": 150,
            'check_callback': function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
                return true;  //allow all other operations
            },
            "themes": {"stripes": false},
            "data": {
                async: false,
                "url": APIURL+"/shiftassignments?asg_date=" + moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                "dataType": "json",
                "success": function (data) {

                }
            }
        },
        "rules": {
            droppable: ["tree-drop"],
            multiple: true,
            deletable: "all",
            draggable: "all"
        },
        "contextmenu": {
            'items' : getContextMenu
        },
        "types": {
            "#": {
                "valid_children": ["SH_LS", "SH_AS", "TO_LS", "TO_AS"]
            },
            "SH_AS": {
                "valid_children": ["ST_LS", "ST_AS"]
            },
            "TO_AS" : {
                "valid_children" : ["ST_LS", "ST_AS"]
            },
            "TO_LS" : {
                "valid_children" : [""]
            },
            "SH_LS": {
                "valid_children": [""]
            },
            "ST_LS": {
                "valid_children": [""]
            },
            "ST_AS": {
                "valid_children": [""]
            }
        },
        "dnd": {
            open_timeout: 100,
            always_copy: true,
            large_drop_target: true
        },
        "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "types"]

    })
```

attached is a screenshot to explain!

I guess effectively I would like to increase the drop-zone and have a 'snap-to' effect to the main '#' node. Maybe its not possible?

[Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/Czi7FIyo)

Comment: Questions without code are less likely to be answered

Comment: What is supposed to happen when there are more than one nodes in the tree already? Which should accept the drop?

Comment: Juan, I have added code now to show the Javascipt where the tree is attached.

Comment: HI Nikolay, I have added the code now to show how tree is created. So you can see that there are a number of node types which can be dropped on the '#' node (these are dragged from another tree). When there is currently no nodes on the '#' then the user can drop a node anywhere within the containing div (which has height=150px). They can then drag any valid children onto this node which is intuitive because they know the child node should be dropped on the parent/target node.

Comment: However, if they want to drag another parent node onto the tree (the '#') they now have a very small area on which to drag it onto. they must drop it within maybe 10px of the existing parent nodes.. I am not sure if I am being clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would listen to events on the div container for the second tree and if a dragged item is then dropped on that container and second tree has only the root, then just add it there.

The code could look something like below. See demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/vo0egex8/).

```
var overSecondTree = false;

$(document).on('dnd_move.vakata', function(e, data) {
    // change icon to `allow drop` if from first tree and over second tree with a single root node
   if ( $('#tree2 li').length === 1 && overSecondTree ) {
        // change icon to `allow drop`
              $('#vakata-dnd').find('i').removeClass('jstree-er').addClass('jstree-ok');
    } else {
                // change icon to `restrict drop`
        $('#vakata-dnd').find('i').removeClass('jstree-ok').addClass('jstree-er');
    }
});

$(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function(e, data) {
    // allow drop to tree2 only if single root node
    if ( $('#tree2 li').length === 1 && overSecondTree) {
        $("#tree2").jstree().create_node('#rootTree2', data.element.text);
    }    
})

$("#tree2").mouseenter(function(event){
     overSecondTree = true;
   if ( $('#tree2 li').length === 1 ) {
      $('#rootTree2').addClass('highlighted');      
   }
})

$("#tree2").mouseleave(function(event){
   overSecondTree = false;
   $('#rootTree2').removeClass('highlighted');
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. My actual structure is a lot more complicated so it took a good bit of tweaking but you set me on the right road! thanks again.